# Security certificate error on my site, what's the solution?

Tags: google-chrome, anti-virus, opera

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH6GH.jpg)My colleagues and friends sometimes can’t go to the site(security certificate error). It happens randomly. What could be the reason? Site is https://rackadvisor.org. Browsers - Opera and Chrome, antiviruses are all different
Is it an error by GlobalSign? What solutions could there be? Sorry, added. Opera 69.0.3686.77, win 10 pro

Comment: The golden rule of asking about errors is to tell exactly what the error says.

Comment: Also, which Windows version and which Opera version?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar when there's a firewall or some other device between you and the internet doing SSL inspection.  It basically imitates a "man-in-the-middle" type of attack.  One that your browser is able to see because the SSL cert returned by the device is not the one it expected.

If you view the SSL cert, you will see that it does not match the actual SSL cert.

> [image: cert path]

---

> [image: cert info]

Either that or you don't have a valid part of the cert chain on your device. (root or intermediate CA)

Sorry, best guess without any more information.

If it is related to what I explained above, then updating the OS and/or browser should resolve it if it is a cert chain issue.

If it is a "man-in-the-middle" style attack, test by checking the cert and comparing to the image I posted and also if possible try a different Internet connection that you know works without errors like this.